# Remove email query string after storing it in a cookie

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

Edit, answered: Maybe this is new? There is an option to remove query parameters in the view settings in Analytics itself. Just remove the parameter email.

My company uses ActiveCampaign for email marketing. When users click links in an email, we pass their AC email as a merge tag in a query string like so ?email=example@example.com. On load, I am storing the email in a cookie like this.

```
<?php

  //Get user's ActiveCampaign email
  $acEmail = $_GET['email'];

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* Export user's ActiveCampaign email to JS variable*/
var acEmail = "<?php echo $acEmail ?>";

//Store user's ActiveCampaign email in cookie
var emailCookie = document.cookie;

if(acEmail) {
  document.cookie = "acEmail=" + acEmail + "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 2020 
  23:59:59 EST; path=/";
}

</script>
```

In Google Analytics, it's passing through the full email in the URL, which is a violation of their privacy policies. I'm wondering if it's possible to write the cookie like this and then remove the email query string completely after the cookie has been written so we are complying with Google's personally identifiable information policies.

I'm aware of several custom javascript snippets, which can be used in Tag Manager to strip the email string. However, all of those completely strip the utm parameters as well, which my analytics team uses to generate reports.

Comment: Use a filter on your views in GA to remove the parameter.

Comment: Ah, yes thank you. I wasn't aware of this feature. Is it new? I haven't been in the analytics panel in about 2 years.